# CAML to get content of referenced list

Tags: caml-query

i got a CAML-Query, which (essentially) pulls the IDs from a lookup field. Then i got another one, which querys the target of the lookup to get the date from that list.

So is there a possibility to design the CAML-Query in a way, that i get the referenced (lookedup) target list with one query instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join lists together like you can tables with CAML. Please refer to the MSDN link.

[CAML Joins MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975.aspx)

Comment: Uh well - somehow i didn't manage to use the word "join" in sharepoint. I will post some results later...